# Gulp replacing single quotes with double quotes?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm pretty new to node.js, but I'm on a team with one other developer. When I build with gulp it changes all the .js files to using single quotes, but when he builds with gulp, it changes them all to use double quotes.

This is really not good because all of our commits end up including every single created .js file generated from our .jsx files.

After searching, I can't find anything that would hint at gulp settings, or anything along those lines. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: a moment will come when someone will comment "please include the gulp code"

Comment: Please include the gulp code;) More seriously, can you post at least the definition of the tasks that transform your script files?